# How to pass values dynamically to Dijktras Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

I am trying to use the following code for Dijktras Algorithm to implement the OSPF routing protocol in java. I want to make this algorithm to except the values for the Edges and their cost dynamically.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Dijkstra {
   private static final Graph.Edge[] GRAPH = {
      new Graph.Edge("a", "b", 7),
      new Graph.Edge("a", "c", 9),
      new Graph.Edge("a", "f", 14),
      new Graph.Edge("b", "c", 10),
      new Graph.Edge("b", "d", 15),
      new Graph.Edge("c", "d", 11),
      new Graph.Edge("c", "f", 2),
      new Graph.Edge("d", "e", 6),
      new Graph.Edge("e", "f", 9),
   };
   private static final String START = "a";
   private static final String END = "e";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Graph g = new Graph(GRAPH);
      g.dijkstra(START);
      g.printPath(END);
      //g.printAllPaths();
   }
}

class Graph {
   private final Map<String, Vertex> graph; // mapping of vertex names to Vertex objects, built from a set of Edges

   /** One edge of the graph (only used by Graph constructor) */
   public static class Edge {
      public final String v1, v2;
      public final int dist;
      public Edge(String v1, String v2, int dist) {
         this.v1 = v1;
         this.v2 = v2;
         this.dist = dist;
      }
   }

   /** One vertex of the graph, complete with mappings to neighbouring vertices */
   public static class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {
      public final String name;
      public int dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // MAX_VALUE assumed to be infinity
      public Vertex previous = null;
      public final Map<Vertex, Integer> neighbours = new HashMap<>();

      public Vertex(String name) {
         this.name = name;
      }

      private void printPath() {
         if (this == this.previous) {
            System.out.printf("%s", this.name);
         } else if (this.previous == null) {
            System.out.printf("%s(unreached)", this.name);
         } else {
            this.previous.printPath();
            System.out.printf(" -> %s(%d)", this.name, this.dist);
         }
      }

      public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
         return Integer.compare(dist, other.dist);
      }
   }

   /** Builds a graph from a set of edges */
   public Graph(Edge[] edges) {
      graph = new HashMap<>(edges.length);

      //one pass to find all vertices
      for (Edge e : edges) {
         if (!graph.containsKey(e.v1)) graph.put(e.v1, new Vertex(e.v1));
         if (!graph.containsKey(e.v2)) graph.put(e.v2, new Vertex(e.v2));
      }

      //another pass to set neighbouring vertices
      for (Edge e : edges) {
         graph.get(e.v1).neighbours.put(graph.get(e.v2), e.dist);
         //graph.get(e.v2).neighbours.put(graph.get(e.v1), e.dist); // also do this for an undirected graph
      }
   }

   /** Runs dijkstra using a specified source vertex */ 
   public void dijkstra(String startName) {
      if (!graph.containsKey(startName)) {
         System.err.printf("Graph doesn't contain start vertex \"%s\"\n", startName);
         return;
      }
      final Vertex source = graph.get(startName);
      NavigableSet<Vertex> q = new TreeSet<>();

      // set-up vertices
      for (Vertex v : graph.values()) {
         v.previous = v == source ? source : null;
         v.dist = v == source ? 0 : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
         q.add(v);
      }

      dijkstra(q);
   }

   /** Implementation of dijkstra's algorithm using a binary heap. */
   private void dijkstra(final NavigableSet<Vertex> q) {      
      Vertex u, v;
      while (!q.isEmpty()) {

         u = q.pollFirst(); // vertex with shortest distance (first iteration will return source)
         if (u.dist == Integer.MAX_VALUE) break; // we can ignore u (and any other remaining vertices) since they are unreachable

         //look at distances to each neighbour
         for (Map.Entry<Vertex, Integer> a : u.neighbours.entrySet()) {
            v = a.getKey(); //the neighbour in this iteration

            final int alternateDist = u.dist + a.getValue();
            if (alternateDist < v.dist) { // shorter path to neighbour found
               q.remove(v);
               v.dist = alternateDist;
               v.previous = u;
               q.add(v);
            } 
         }
      }
   }

   /** Prints a path from the source to the specified vertex */
   public void printPath(String endName) {
      if (!graph.containsKey(endName)) {
         System.err.printf("Graph doesn't contain end vertex \"%s\"\n", endName);
         return;
      }

      graph.get(endName).printPath();
      System.out.println();
   }
   /** Prints the path from the source to every vertex (output order is not guaranteed) */
   public void printAllPaths() {
      for (Vertex v : graph.values()) {
         v.printPath();
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

I tried following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       Map<String, ArrayList<String>> m = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

       ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
       l1.add("R1");
       l1.add("R2");
       l1.add("50");
       ArrayList<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
       l2.add("R1");
       l2.add("R3");
       l2.add("50");
       ArrayList<String> l3 = new ArrayList<String>();
       l3.add("R4");
       l3.add("R3");
       l3.add("50");
       ArrayList<String> l4 = new ArrayList<String>();
       l4.add("R4");
       l4.add("R2");
       l4.add("50");

       m.put("X", l1);
       m.put("Y", l2);
       m.put("Z", l3);
       m.put("W", l4);

       System.out.println(m);
       Graph.Edge[] GRAPH=null;
    //   private static final Graph.Edge[] GRAPH = null;
       int i=0;
       for(String key:m.keySet()){
           System.out.println(key+m.get(key).get(0)+m.get(key).get(1)+m.get(key).get(2));
           GRAPH[i]=new Graph.Edge(m.get(key).get(0), m.get(key).get(1),Integer.parseInt(m.get(key).get(2)));
           i++;
       }
       String START = "a";
       String END = "e";
      Graph g = new Graph(GRAPH);
      g.dijkstra(START);
      g.printPath(END);
      //g.printAllPaths();
   }
}
```

I want to pass the value from the hashmap to the dijktras algorithm. and initialize all the edges with the data stored in the HashMap
Note: `hashmap<LinkID,<Edge,Edge,Cost>>`

Please Suggest where I am going wrong or suggest a better of passing the values dynamically to this [Algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Java)

Comment: You could start by initializing the `Graph.Edge[] GRAPH` array, because as you have it now, it will throw an exception. `Graph.Edge[] GRAPH = new Graph.Edge[m.size()]`

Comment: Thank you Nadir, That helped

Answer (score 0):

The example you link uses a hard-coded array

```
private static final Graph.Edge[] GRAPH = {
      new Graph.Edge("a", "b", 7),
      new Graph.Edge("a", "c", 9),
      new Graph.Edge("a", "f", 14),
      new Graph.Edge("b", "c", 10),
      new Graph.Edge("b", "d", 15),
      new Graph.Edge("c", "d", 11),
      new Graph.Edge("c", "f", 2),
      new Graph.Edge("d", "e", 6),
      new Graph.Edge("e", "f", 9),
};
```

for initialization of the graph. First of all, it is a bit surprising that you use seem to use strings for encoding of the distances. For conversion, you need to iterate over the keys of your `Map` (which would enumerate the edges) and create an instance of `Graph.Edege` for each, which would then populated with both the vertex identifiers and the distance. Iteration over keys of a `Map` can be found in [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm) example.

Comment: Thank you Codor, I used map.keyset() to iterate over the keys in the map.